# Match until the first character

Tags: regex

This is my string:

```
[TEST1 lorem ipsum123][TEST2 lorem ipsum123][TEST3 lorem ipsum123]Test4
```

I would like to match `[TEST1 lorem ipsum123]`. From *TEST1* until *]* it can be anything.

This is what I have tried

```
TEST1.+\]
```

But it will match the string until the last `]` character. How can I let it match until the first character instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of matching anything, use this:

`TEST1[^\]]+\]`

Comment: That didn't work for me but `TEST1[^\]]+\]` did it well! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use this pattern:

`\[TEST\d[^[]+\]`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xdW5j5/2)

**Explanation**:

- `\[` - match `[` that come before **TEST**
- `\d` - match one digit after **TEST**
- `[^[]` - this match anything except `[`, so it can match anything until the first `]`
- `\]` - is for match `\]` at the end of the match

Comment: Thanks! That would work fine but if I would like to use the same case for `TEST3`, it wouldn't work anymore.

Comment: It because your question is not clear, anyway I edited my answer